# dismiss is never called when navigate fragments

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using Navigation. And let's say, I have A_fragment an B_Fragment.

A_fragment is the Home Fragment, and it has many dialogs when it shows up such as event or notice.
And B_fragment, it can be directed by deeplink.

So, When I enter the app by deeplink, It will show A_fragment first and then B_fragment.

I'd like to dismiss all the dialogs of A_fragment when it navigate to B_fragment. However, `onDismiss()` nor `onDestroyView()` are not called. I expected the dialog lifecycle belongs to the fragment where the dialogs are created at first time, but it isn't.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try alertDialog_object.dismiss();

Comment: I call it but this doesn't work properly. I just want to restrict the visibility to a fragment, like when a fragment dies, the dialog dies too. @RakeshSaini